# Want to write a trigger after UPDATE

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have writen a trigger which will log every data updation and will log `previous_value, new_value, field_name` and many more. But the problem is i have **77 fields** in my table. So, it's difficult to write `IF ENDIF` for each field so i want to know is it possible to write using loop?

Already asked in dba.stackexchange.com but did not get any fruitfull answer yet, link below::

[Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164635/want-to-write-a-trigger-after-update)

I have tried so far::

```
BEGIN

IF(OLD.company_name != NEW.company_name) THEN
 INSERT INTO elm_activity_log (user_id, action_on, action, action_col, action_old_value, action_new_value, action_at, action_on_id) VALUES (NEW.updated_by, "company", "update", "company_name", OLD.company_name, NEW.company_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NEW.company_id);
END IF;
IF(OLD.company_first_name != NEW.company_first_name) THEN
 INSERT INTO elm_activity_log (user_id, action_on, action, action_col, action_old_value, action_new_value, action_at, action_on_id) VALUES (NEW.updated_by, "company", "update", "company_first_name", OLD.company_first_name, NEW.company_first_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NEW.company_id);
END IF;

END
```

Please help, or any suggestion will be very helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not within mysql. I would dump the contents of information_schema.columns into excel and build the code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this automatically but I understand your point. As long as your are smart enough, being lazy is actually a quality in computer sciences.

I usually overcome this kind of issues with "automatic programming" :  make code that generate code.

You have 2 options to generate your SQL statements:

```
1. Pure SQL 
2. Programming language
```

Here's a beginning of solution using SQL :

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT
    (
        'IF(OLD.company_name != NEW.company_name) THEN \n
         INSERT INTO elm_activity_log (user_id, action_on, action, action_col, action_old_value, action_new_value, action_at, action_on_id) VALUES (NEW.updated_by, "company", "update", "', T.column_name,'", OLD.', T.column_name, ', NEW.', T.column_name,', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NEW.company_id); \n
        END IF; \n
        \n
        '
    ) as SQLstatement

FROM
(
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE column_name NOT IN ('id') 
      AND table_name = 'your_table'  
      AND table_schema = 'database_name'
) T
```

It might work straight, it might have to be rewritten a litlle bit. You have not provided your table DLL  so I can hardly test if it work.

The idea is to generate a row for each column name, containing the SQL statement for that column's trigger part. You can then export the results of this query into a text file, et voila.

Adapt accordingly in the nested query : table_name, table_schema, and columns that you want to exclude from the logging (I set 'id').

Note that in the SELECT CONCAT, I added some `/n` which should end up in carriage returns in the output